# Последовательная задержка на Sass для дочерних элементов?

Tags: html, css, sass, scss

Всем привет! Как с помощью `Sass` создать из этого более изящное решение для последовательного увеличения `transition-delay` у дочерних элементов?

Вот, чтобы как в примере ZOE - последовательно показывались иконки соц.сетей.
[Пример - пункт Zoe](https://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/).

```
.myClass {
  &:nth-child(1) {
    transition: all 1s ease-out 0.5s;
  }
  &:nth-child(2) {
    transition: all 1s ease-out 0.7s;
  }
  &:nth-child(3) {
    transition: all 1s ease-out 0.9s;
  }
  &:nth-child(4) {
    transition: all 1s ease-out 1.1s;
  }
  &:nth-child(5) {
    transition: all 1s ease-out 1.3s;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В `Sass` существует директива управления - `@for`. Её можно использовать для таких задач. (Рабочий пример на [Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/St1myL/pen/aYYqGB)).

`Sass`:

```
//Создаём переменные для управления значениями
$items: 4
$transition: 500ms

//Каждому элементу будет прибавлять по 0.060s
@for $i from 0 through $items 
  &:nth-child(#{$i + 1}) 
    transition-delay: $transition+(60ms*($i))
```

Компилированная версия:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper:hover .item {
  transform: translateY(50px);
  background-color: crimson;
}

.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: tomato;
  transition: 500ms;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  transition-delay: 500ms;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  transition-delay: 560ms;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  transition-delay: 620ms;
}

.item:nth-child(4) {
  transition-delay: 680ms;
}

.item:nth-child(5) {
  transition-delay: 740ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Круто! Большое спасибо! Это то, что мне нужно:)

Comment: @Make_dev, был рад помочь:)